# Copy contents from one directory and paste in another, IOError: [Errno 13] python

Tags: python, copy, shutil

I've looked through the forum at several posts similar to this w/ the same error, but am still unable to fix it. I am getting the IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/..../.' when using shutil.copy(). Here is the code:

```
import subprocess, os, shutil

for i in range(1,3):
    path = 'C:/Users/TEvans/Desktop/Testing/slope%d' % i 
    if not os.path.exists(path): 
        os.makedirs(path)
    os.chdir(path)
    for j in range(1,4):
        path1 = 'C:/Users/TEvans/Desktop/Testing/slope%d/r%d' % (i, j)
        if not os.path.exists(path1): 
            os.makedirs(path1)
        src = 'C:/Users/TEvans/Desktop/Testing/PP%d/S%d' % (i, j)
        dst = 'C:/Users/TEvans/Desktop/Testing/slope%d/r%d' % (i, j)
        shutil.copy(src, dst)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sutra.py", line 14, in <module>
    shutil.copy(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 117, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/TEvans/Desktop/Testing/PP1/S1'
```

Answer (score 3):

shutil.copy copies a file. You want shutil.copytree to recurisvely copy a whole directory:

```
import subprocess, os, shutil

for i in range(1,3):
    path = 'C:/Users/TEvans/Desktop/Testing/slope%d' % i 
    if not os.path.exists(path): 
        os.makedirs(path)
    os.chdir(path)
    for j in range(1,4):
        src = 'C:/Users/TEvans/Desktop/Testing/PP%d/S%d' % (i, j)
        dst = 'C:/Users/TEvans/Desktop/Testing/slope%d/r%d' % (i, j)
        shutil.copytree(src, dst)
```

Answer (score 1):

shutil.copy is used for copying a file and not a directory. It needs a file as first parameter and directory or filename as second parameter. If the second parameter is a file name it will do copy and rename the file.

For copying a directory, The best way is to use `distutils's dir_util` library package.

```
>>> import distutils.dir_util
>>>
>>> dir(distutils.dir_util)
['DistutilsFileError', 'DistutilsInternalError', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__revision__', '_build_cmdtuple', '_path_created', 'copy_tree', 'create_tree', 'ensure_relative', 'errno', 'log', 'mkpath', 'os', 'remove_tree']
>>>
```

copy_tree function will help you to copy the whole directory.

Refer to the following definition.

```
>>> help(distutils.dir_util.copy_tree)
Help on function copy_tree in module distutils.dir_util:

copy_tree(src, dst, preserve_mode=1, preserve_times=1, preserve_symlinks=0, upda
te=0, verbose=1, dry_run=0)
    Copy an entire directory tree 'src' to a new location 'dst'.

    Both 'src' and 'dst' must be directory names.  If 'src' is not a
    directory, raise DistutilsFileError.  If 'dst' does not exist, it is
    created with 'mkpath()'.  The end result of the copy is that every
    file in 'src' is copied to 'dst', and directories under 'src' are
    recursively copied to 'dst'.  Return the list of files that were
    copied or might have been copied, using their output name.  The
    return value is unaffected by 'update' or 'dry_run': it is simply
    the list of all files under 'src', with the names changed to be
    under 'dst'.

    'preserve_mode' and 'preserve_times' are the same as for
    'copy_file'; note that they only apply to regular files, not to
    directories.  If 'preserve_symlinks' is true, symlinks will be
    copied as symlinks (on platforms that support them!); otherwise
    (the default), the destination of the symlink will be copied.
    'update' and 'verbose' are the same as for 'copy_file'.

>>>
```

Comment: Then you should also tell what is used to copy a directory

Comment: @AhmadTaha Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are on a Windows machine probably on a Windows Vista or later version; Seeing this is Errno 13 I am pretty much sure you haven't run your script as Administrator. Try to run your script as administrator or if you are executing the script via command prompt try to run the cmd.exe as administrator then execute it.

Try to use backslashes cause you are in windows and while using backslashes try to use raw strings i.e.

```
path = r'C:\Users\TEvans\Desktop\Testing\slope%d'
```